# Possible account merge?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I'm not sure if this should go here or on the [meta meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), but since it applies specifically to gamedev.stackexchange, I thought this a good place to start?

I recently stumbled upon this [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/13626/13085) and [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/13875/13085), which were asked and answered by these two users:

- [diede apers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/7991/diede-apers)
- [diede apers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/8115/diede-apers)

Based on the text of the answer, and the fact that neither "user" has any activity other than that question and answer, it appears that it was just one person who didn't bother creating an account for their one issue (although they were persistent enough to come back and share their answer). My question here is two-part:

1. Should these accounts be merged?
2. (Probably more suited for MetaMeta) how should this situation in general be handled? I feel like merging inactive users that *seem* to be the same user isn't something we want to do blindly, and should be considered on a case-by-case basis. However, is consolidating their accounts/activity something that is worth the time and effort involved in doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see a situation like that just flag it.

Comment: Exactly what I should've done. Don't know why I didn't think of it...